# read two files from two paths at within same loop_python

Tags: python, file, loops

I have two paths each path contains many files, each file contains data for one day. I need to read the file from the first path, and the other file from the other path that corresponds to the same day. [in the same python loop I want to read the file of the first day in each path]. The files are with the same name and sequence in each path.
I'm trying to use `os.listdir(path)` in for loop instead of `with open (file) as file` because I want to read the file as a data frame using pandas. Then use pandas to do data aggregation for each file.

Comment: How do you know which file in the second path corresponds to each file in the first path, without openning them?

Comment: Arethe number of files and their sequence same? More importantly what is the naming convention for the files?

Comment: The files have the same names and order regarding the date as (20191010.csv in the first path and 20191010 in the second path). in other words the first file in the first path with the first path in the second path and so on so forth@Aryerez

Comment: The sequence of files and order in two paths are the same @Sayandip Dutta

Comment: `with open("file1_path") as a, open("file2_path") as b: ...`. All you need is to construct the path for both files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have in each path more than 1000 files and in each round, I need to read each file, doing a process, then store a processed file @Henry Yik, I'm trying to do the following <'for file,file1 in os.listdir(path+folder,user_path):
        .....'>

Comment: I want to open the files using pandas because I want to to do data aggregation for each file @HenryYik that's why with open does not work with me

Comment: Then just use `zip`. `for file1, file2 in zip(os.listdir(path1),os.listdir(path2)):...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you are sure, that a file always exists in both directories.

Is this what you are asking?

```
path1 = "path1"
path2 = "path2"
for fname in os.listdir(path1):
    fname1 = os.path.join(path1, fname)
    fname2 = os.path.join(path2, fname)
        # do your processing here
```

If it can happen, that a file exists in path1 but not in path 2 you have to check with `os.path.isfile()` the presence of the other file before opening and skip if absent

Comment: changed my answer to not use open